# Why this won't jump to the correct line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/13/) please see the table that shows all the comments, and their time.

When the video starts playing, it starts showing each comment as elapsed time of the video goes by.

The problem that I'm facing is that it won't jump to correct line in the table(The table kinda looks like textarea)
It goes back and forth, and it won't aim.
I want correct line to be shown on the top position of the table every time when each comment pops up.
It should scroll, and follow current comment's line in the table.

How can I fix this?  Can anyone modify and update my jsfiddle?

**Javascript**

```
var row= '';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var fixedTime = 0;
    $('#video').on('timeupdate',function(e){
        if(this.currentTime.toFixed() != fixedTime){
            showComments(fixedTime);
            fixedTime = this.currentTime.toFixed()
        }  
    });

}); 

var comments = [
    {'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},
    {'time':'11','message':'hello! 11 secs has past'},
    {'time':'10','message':'hello! 10-2 secs has past'},
    {'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},
    {'time':'20','message':'hello! 20 secs has past'},
    {'time':'21','message':'hello! 21 secs has past'},
    {'time':'20','message':'hello! 20-2 secs has past'},
    {'time':'25','message':'hello! 25 secs has past'},
    {'time':'30','message':'hello! 30 secs has past'}
];


function showComments(time){
    var coms = findComments(time);
    if(coms[0]){
            $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600).fadeOut(100);
            $('.newsticker').append("<p style='margin-left:400px;opacity:0'>"+coms[0].message+"</p>");
            $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);

            var row = "tr.comment" + time;
            $("tr").css("background-color","#ffffff");
            jQuery(row).each(function() {
                $(this).css("background","#87cefa");
                $('div#container').animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery(this).offset().top
                }, 500);
        });  
    }
}

function findComments(time){
    return $.grep(comments, function(item){
      return item.time == time;
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <body>
        <div class="newsticker"> 
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <video id="video" width="320" height="180" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media"><source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </body>

<div id="container" style="border:solid 1px;height:70px; width:500px; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <table border="0" height="100" width="400">
    <tr class="comment5">
        <td>00:00:05</td>
        <td>hello! 5 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment10">
        <td>00:00:10</td>
        <td>hello! 10 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment10">
        <td>00:00:10</td>
        <td>hello! 10-2 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment11">
        <td>00:00:11</td>
        <td>hello! 11 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment20">
        <td>00:00:20</td>
        <td>hello! 20 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment20">
        <td>00:00:20</td>
        <td>hello! 20-2 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment21">
        <td>00:00:21</td>
        <td>hello! 21 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment25">
        <td>00:00:25</td>
        <td>hello! 25 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="comment30">
        <td>00:00:30</td>
        <td>hello! 30 secs has past</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

.newsticker p{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: No answer? anyone please!

Comment: I'm looking into it. I see some problems, but no solution.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks!!! I appreciate it! Anyone else can solve this problem?????

Comment: For example, you're using `.offset()`, which is relative to the document. You should use `.position()`, which is relative to the closest positioned parent (so you should also give your container div `position: relative`). But that alone is not enough (http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/15/), maybe it's because you're using a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know *why*, but the values provided by `offset().top` for the comment rows are way too big to be useful... they just make the div scroll down all the way.

I replaced it with the DOM property `offsetTop` and it seems to work fine :

```
$('div#container').animate({
    scrollTop: this.offsetTop
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/19/

Comment: Because `.offset()` is relative to the document, and `offsetTop` is relative to the parent. It's strange that jQuery's `.position().top` (which I [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/15/)) is giving a different result than `[0].offsetTop`.

Comment: `jQuery(this)[0].offsetTop` is simply `this.offsetTop` :)

Comment: Thanks it's weird isn't it?

Comment: @MiklosAubert if possible could you fix your code following other guys advices?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zqhF/17/

The fixes

1. The offset is too large, as pointed out by Miklos.  `jQuery(this)[0].offsetTop`.
2. The `comments` array isn't being passed into your `findComments()` function, it's not in the right context.  What I did was modify the functions to accept the comments as variable: `showComments(fixedTime, comments);` and `findComments(time, comments);`
3. Your animate function can be called twice (since you have multiple comments with the same time), causing the jumping around you see.  You can fix this by ensuring it only runs on the first iteration, by using a loop index:

   - Set the index `jQuery(row).each(function(index) {`
   - Then use the index:

Like so:

```
if(index == 0)
{
    $('div#container').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(this)[0].offsetTop
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: so what exactly will be different from Miklos'? in what kind of situation, different result will occur?

Comment: comments is available via closure, it doesn't have to be passed.

Comment: @MKK - For instance, when the video gets to 20 seconds, it jumps to the first 20 second comment, then the second one.  My solution prevents that from occurring by limiting the scrolling to the first 20 second comment.

Comment: @Axel That's great!! Thanks I wish I could give best answer to you but he did it first. I appreciate it anyway!!!

Comment: No worries. Just happy to help :)